# Why don't types with invalid inheritance get rejected when passed as template parameters?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

As we all know, classes can't be inherited from fundamental types and from classes that are marked as `final`. But despite that, the code presented below compiles without any problems on Clang 12 and GCC 9.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Inheriter : public T{};

int main()
{
    std::void_t<Inheriter<int>>();
}
```

Comment: [Substitution failure is not an error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

Comment: Note that `Inheriter<int> i;` would fail with `error: base specifier must name a class` as you expect https://godbolt.org/z/516qWc58P

Comment: is there a particular reason you used `void_t` ? I mean if you use a template that requires an "ok" type as argument you get the expected error, eg `std::vector<Inheriter<int>>`. In other words: is the question about `void_t` or about `Inheriter<int>` specifically? You seem to mix two things which could actually make 2 seperate questions

Comment: @NathanOliver substitution failure is not an error whenever there are other substitution  candidates, but that's not a case here.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number this question is about `void_t` not discarding template parameters which are ill-formed

Comment: interesting question. I cannot point to what causes this, but consider that you can do the same with `template <typename T> struct foo {};` as it doesnt actually need to instantiate whatever T is (similar to `void_t`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will only be an error due to the inheritance if the template specialization `Inheriter<int>` is *instantiated*.

Simply using the specialization, e.g. as a template argument, does not cause implicit instantiation. Roughly speaking implicit instantiation of the class template specialization happens only if it is used in a context that requires the class to be complete or otherwise depends on class completeness.

`std::void_t` is defined as

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

There is nothing in this alias template that requires the template argument to be a complete type. As a consequence no implicit instantiation will happen.

The program is therefore well-formed and the compiler should not reject it.

Comment: in other words, if it's not instantiated, it did not happen ;)   -  well. almost true... syntax is checked.

Comment: Instantiation is the keyword. You`d better highlight it if SO had provided the means.

Answer (score 6):

Per [[expr.type.conv]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2):

> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression. Otherwise, if the type is cv void and the initializer is () or {} (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of type void that performs no initialization

Meaning `T()` when `T` is `void` (as in your case) is a no-op, and `void_t` is [defined as](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.alias#3) (per [temp.alias])

```
template<typename...> using void_t = void;
```

Meaning that if a valid type is supplied, then it will always become `void`.

Here's my take:

The code is syntactically correct, and if type substitution succeeds it is provably a no-op. Per the [as-if rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#footnote-7), the compiler can prove that the program without this line altogether has identical runtime behavior, and therefore it is safe to ignore it completely. I can reproduce this behavior in MSVC, GCC, and Clang.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler requires that the code be free of syntactic errors. And the sample snippet doesn't have any. Only when you create an `Inheriter` object can the compiler raise any errors (such as the ones you are expecting)

Comment: Well, if I write `std::void_t<decltype(Inheriter<int>{})>();` there wouldn't be any syntactic errors as well, but that led to the compilation error

Comment: @icant, yes, but notice that `std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Inheriter<int>>())>();` doesn't led to any errors.